# How to reload data with time in timepicker?

Tags: iphone, datetime

How do i reload time into timepicker after selcting it.Was able to reload date

```
[pickerView setDate:[self getDateFromString:lblDOB.text] animated:NO];
```

where  `UIDatePicker *pickerView;`

How do i load time?

```
 -(NSDate*)getDateFromString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:kDateMMDDYYYY];
    NSDate *dateParameter = [df dateFromString:string];
    [df release];
    return dateParameter;
}
```

used this only for getting date.

for Time i used this

```
pickerView1.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
```

how i reload this time to timepicker.

Comment: show us your code inside `getDateFromString` method, and what format are you passing in `lblDOB.text`?

Comment: please refer to updated code above.

Comment: have you given hour/minute format to `kDateMMDDYYYY`?

Comment: i have used that only for date. for time could not..can u please help with that

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the date format of your macro `kDateMMDDYYYY`

use like below:

```
#define kDateMMDDYYYY @"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm"
```

After use the same function and pass lblDOB.text as below

```
lblDOB.text = @"2010/10/06 10:20";
[pickerView setDate:[self getDateFromString:lblDOB.text] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here i am setting the date likewise you can set the time:

```
    NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate* date;
    if ([textField.text isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [textField.text length] == 0) {
        date = [NSDate date];
    }
    else {
        date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:textField.text];
    }
    [dobPicker setDate:date];
```